# Handling 405 errors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to handle `405` (`Method not Allowed`) errors generated from *WebApi*.

*E.g.*: Basically this error will be handled whenever someone calls my Api with a Post request instead of a Get one.

I'd like to do this programatically (i.e. no IIS configuration), right now there are no documentation of handling this kind of error and the `IExceptionHandler` is not triggered when this exception happens.

Any ideas ?

Comment: The webserver is an IIS on Windows Server?

Comment: Yes, but I don't have control over the server or IIS, so it would be preferable if there is a way to handle it programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial response:
By looking at the HTTP Message lifecycle from [here](https://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf), there is a possibility to add a Message Handler early in the pipeline, before HttpRoutingDispatcher.

So, create a handler class:

```
public class NotAllowedMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            switch (response.StatusCode)
            {
                case HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed:
                {
                    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed)
                    {
                        Content = new StringContent("Custom Error Message")
                    };
                }
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

In your WebApiConfig, in Register method add the following line:

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new NotAllowedMessageHandler());
```

You can check the status code of the response and generate a custom error message based on it.